# Open ppt file in a new browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, powerpoint

A link that contains a .pdf such as the following opens in a new tab:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://somePDF.pdf">Download</a>
```

Is it possible to make a Powerpoint file, .ppt, open in a new browser tab instead of making the user download the file?

I have tried this the following but this makes a user download the file:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://somePPT.ppt">Download</a>
```

I am not sure if this is possible and have not been able to find any information on it so I am posting here.

Comment: Updated.  I tagged it with Java instead of JavaScript by mistake.

Comment: @Mdd You tagged your question with "Java". But your question has nothing to do with Java...just Javascript. That's all Doorknob meant. People often confuse the two things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the user's browser isn't able to display the file and has no plugin that can display the file, it will offer the file as a download.

If you can export the PowerPoint slides to PDF or HTML, they are more likely to be displayed in the browser.

Comment: I was thinking that the browser would handle this and that there was nothing that an html attribute could do.  But I was not able to find much information.  Thanks!

Comment: worth mention that not everyone has a PDF browser plugin, either; I quite deliberately do not  :)

Comment: A `ppt` won't work in most scenarios. It might work on Windows, in Internet Explorer if PowerPoint (or PowerPoint Player) is installed. This is unlikely to represent your entire user base.

Comment: @Eevee I'm glad you mentioned that - browser vendors are starting to display PDF in a native HTML viewer now, so you don't need the Adobe Reader plugin.

Answer (score 1):

you could check if the browser has installed an pdf plugin, and if not use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to convert your pdf into an html page.

could look like this:

```
function hasPDFPlugin() {
   for(var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
      if(navigator.plugins[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf('pdf') >== 0) {
        return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}

if(!hasPDFPlugin()) {
  // do the pdf.js stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of google docs it can viewable.add file location after url=
https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=

ex-https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://example.in/filename.ppt